# How to join two tables based on some condition in sql?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I need help to join two tables to get output. I tell you the scenario. Could you please help me.

Example:

I have one sql query:
Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT schemaname ,objectname,usename,
         HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel,
         HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins,
         HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd,
         HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del,
         HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref 
  FROM (
     SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj 
     FROM pg_tables 
     WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal') 
     UNION 
     SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj 
     FROM pg_views 
     WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
  ) AS objs,
  (SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs ORDER BY fullobj
) 
WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true) 
   and schemaname='medaff' 
   and usename not in ('rdsdb','clustersa','prdrscl01master') 
   and objectname in RES;
```

The above query is giving some output:

```
Table 1

schemaname  objectname   usename           sel  ins  upd  del  ref
medaff      dmn_category medaff_dev_admin  True True True True True
medaff      dmn_category emea_dev_admin    True True True True True
medaff      dmn_category cdeadmin          True True True True True
```

I have other table which have some records :

```
Table 2:

application_name  tablename
smart_source      dmn_category
```

How to join these two tables to get the application name also in the final output:

```
application_name schemaname  objectname   usename           sel  ins  upd  del  ref  
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category medaff_dev_admin  True True True True True
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category emea_dev_admin    True True True True True
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category cdeadmin          True True True True True
```

Comment: You need a field in the second table that matches a field in the first table.   Do the first table contain application name or table name?    Is ObjectName in table 1 the same as tablename in table2?

Comment: Are you sure this is Amazon Redshift? I am asking, because I think they are using the standard concatenation operator `||` while you are using `+` here: `schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj` which I only know from SQL Server.

Comment: yes it is running in amazon redshift

Answer (score 1):

When you want to represent 2 tables you can use `inner join on` but for this you need to have something in commun in each table.
For example :

```
select t.name, o.code from FirstTable t inner join OtherTable o on t.code = o.code
```

Comment: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables. Getting this error.

Comment: @Shivam i just tried it on my computer and worked fine. The tables must have something that match or else the inner join doesnt work

Comment: okay.. But I am not getting where I need to keep first query ?

Comment: I am trying this:

Answer (score 0):

I think the point here is you want to join a complex query result with another table? You can achieve it by:

1. Using `WITH tbl AS (.....)` then join the other table on `tbl`(query result).
2. Creating a `VIEW` for your first result, then join the other table with this view.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. `UNION` should be `UNION ALL`, though, and

```
) AS objs,
(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs
```

should be

```
) AS objs
CROSS JOIN pg_user AS usrs
```

and

```
ORDER BY fullobj
```

is superfluous, because the DBMS is allowed to ignore `ORDER BY` inside subqueries. (If you want your results ordered, then place `ORDER BY fullobj` at the end of your query.)

But anyway, all you seem to want is to join the table2:

```
) AS objs
CROSS JOIN pg_user AS usrs
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.tablename = objs.objectname
```

The complete query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT
    table2.application_name,
    objs.schemaname,
    objs.objectname,
    usrs.usename,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.schemaname, 'usage') AS sel,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.schemaname, 'usage') AS ins,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.schemaname, 'usage')  AS del,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, objs.fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, objs.schemaname, 'usage') AS ref
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      schemaname, 
      't' AS obj_type, 
      tablename AS objectname, 
      schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj
    FROM pg_tables 
    WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal') 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      schemaname, 
      'v' AS obj_type, 
      viewname AS objectname, 
      schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj 
    FROM pg_views 
    WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
  ) AS objs
  CROSS JOIN pg_user AS usrs
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.tablename = objs.objectname
)
WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true)
  and schemaname = 'medaff' 
  and usename not in ('rdsdb', 'clustersa', 'prdrscl01master')
ORDER BY schemaname, objectname, application_name, usename;
```

Comment: Can you please give me full query with join?

Comment: You should actually be able to do this yourself. Anyway, I've added the query to my answer.

Comment: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Comment: Ah, okay. I've looked up the error and it seems you cannot join pg_views and your own tables in Redshift. At least this is how I understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326426/amazon-redshift-error-error-0a000-specified-types-or-functions-one-per-info