# How to join result of queries in sql?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do JOIN of two tables but not getting the right output. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

I have one sql query which is generating output.

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT schemaname ,objectname,usename,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref FROM(SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal') UNION SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')) AS objs,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs ORDER BY fullobj) WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true) and schemaname='medaff' and usename not in ('rdsdb','clustersa','prdrscl01master')
```

Output of above query is:

```
schemaname  objectname   usename           sel  ins  upd  del  ref
medaff      dmn_category medaff_dev_admin  True True True True True
medaff      dmn_category emea_dev_admin    True True True True True
medaff      dmn_category cdeadmin          True True True True True
```

I have another query:

query 2 :

```
select * from medaff.imedical_metadata
```

Output of above query :

```
application_name  tablename
smart_source      dmn_category
```

How to JOIN these two outputs to get the below output:

```
application_name schemaname  objectname   usename           sel  ins  upd  del  ref  
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category medaff_dev_admin  True True True True True
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category emea_dev_admin    True True True True True
smart_source     medaff      dmn_category cdeadmin          True True True True True
```

Could you help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377354)

Comment: Hi i do not think base  query are not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 

(SELECT * FROM (SELECT schemaname ,objectname,usename,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref FROM(SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal') UNION SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')) AS objs,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs ORDER BY fullobj) WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true) and schemaname='medaff' and usename not in ('rdsdb','clustersa','prdrscl01master')
) b inner join medaff.imedical_metadata x on x.tablename = b.objectname
```

Comment: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.