# Column '' has unsupported type "information_schema.sql_identifier"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I am trying to test my stored procedure in MySQL workbench/j. I get an error when I am trying to call the stored procedure.

I have created a table to store the result of my stored procedure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ableok 
(
  name VARCHAR(50) ENCODE lzo
 );
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetDistSchema()
AS '
BEGIN
  SELECT table_schema INTO ableok FROM information_schema.tables;
 END;
 '
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is how i call my stored procedure in SQL workbench/j:

```
call sp_getdistschema();
```

Result:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
call sp_getdistschema()

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Column "table_schema" has unsupported type "information_schema.sql_identifier".; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The SELECT ... INTO structure is used to store a query result into variables.  It looks as though you are really just trying to populate the distTable directly.  Try this instead:

Update: When processing the information schema in Redshift/PostgreSQL, you apparently need to convert the column datatypes using CAST:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetDistSchema()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO distTable SELECT DISTINCT CAST(table_schema AS VARCHAR) FROM information_schema.tables;
END;
```

Comment: I get new error when trying this: Column "*SELECT*.table_schema" has unsupported type "information_schema.sql_identifier". Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.(Repeated 7 times). Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]

Comment: Do you get any error when you run the INSERT statement outside of the procedure?

Comment: Yes same error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]

Comment: Did you see the update to the original answer and try the CAST?

Comment: Yup, could it be because the information_schema is running at leader note while the queries on normal tables are running on compute node?

Comment: Apparently that is the case - see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326426/amazon-redshift-error-error-0a000-specified-types-or-functions-one-per-info which states: In Redshift:

1) queries against information_schema run on the leader node only.
2) queries against any "normal" tables run on compute nodes only.
You cannot mix and match 1 and 2. :-(

Answer (score 0):

As @user9601310 mentioned (up voted), you need to CAST the column data types.

I was scratching my head too, even in plain old Postgres when your using the information_schema.

This will 'describe' a table or a view, but won't work unless the query columns are cast as VARCHAR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_desc(p_tablename VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE(vtable_name VARCHAR, vcolumn_name VARCHAR, vdata_type VARCHAR)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$          
     BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT
        table_name::VARCHAR,
        column_name::VARCHAR,
        data_type::VARCHAR
      FROM
        information_schema.columns
      WHERE
        table_name ILIKE p_tablename;
     END;
     $function$
```

SELECT * FROM public.fn_desc('any_table_or_view');

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift/Postgres, I would use,

```
CREATE or replace view v_schema_table_columns AS
SELECT 
    table_name::varchar l_table_name, 
    column_name::varchar l_column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).