# Save stored procedure result set in a table

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have created a stored procedure that returns the distinct table_schema name. My database is using redshift and I am using SQL workbench/J to create it.

As recommended by AMAZON Redshift, we can use a cursor to return the result set. Below is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_dist_schema(rsout INOUT refcursor)
AS $$
BEGIN 
  OPEN rsout FOR SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
CALL get_dist_schema('sname');
FETCH ALL FROM sname;

commit;
```

Result from FETCH ALL FROM sname is as shown below:

```
table_schema
tableA
tableB
tableC
tableD
```

I want to save the result in a table such that when I do select statement for a table, the same result will appear.

I have tried this:

```
BEGIN;
CALL get_dist_schema('sname');
FETCH ALL FROM sname INTO public.distTable
```

The error say:

```
Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "INTO" 
Position: 22;
```

Is there any way I can save the result into a table?
FETCH ALL FROM sname INTO public.distTable

UPDATE:
IF I USE SELECT INTO:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_dist_schema(rsout INOUT refcursor)
AS $$
BEGIN 
  OPEN rsout FOR SELECT DISTINCT table_schema INTO public.distTable FROM information_schema.tables;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

ERROR:

```
CALL get_dist_schema('sname')

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Column "table_schema" has unsupported type "information_schema.sql_identifier".;
```

Comment: Can't you just use `CREATE TABLE distTable AS SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables`?

Comment: I am required to use a stored procedure as I need to fetch data dynamically from redshift. I have tried a similar method u have suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878541/stored-procedure-column-has-unsupported-type-information-schema-sql-identif/63879835?noredirect=1#comment112988881_63879835 but having issues

Comment: Does the table in which you want to insert already exist? Have you tried to wrap the result of the stored procedure with a `SELECT INTO` ([docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_INTO.html))?

Comment: yes, the table is already exists. I have tried to SELECT INTO from information_schema to the table. I have raised a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878541/stored-procedure-column-has-unsupported-type-information-schema-sql-identif/63879835?noredirect=1#comment112988881_63879835

Comment: I have edited my code above with select into

Comment: I'm having this problem, did you find a solution? Redshift is a right pina when it comes to utilising system tables for anything useful!