# SQL: Divide long text in multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to divide a long text in multiple rows; there are other questions similar to this one but none of them worked for me.
What I have

```
ID | Message
----------------------------------
1  | Very looooooooooooooooong text
2  | Short text
```

What I would like to do is divide that string every n characters
Result if `n = 15`:

```
Id                    | Message
------------------------------------------
1                     | Very looooooooo
1                     | oooooooong text
2                     | Short text
```

Even better if the split is done at the first space after n character.

I tried with string_split and substring but I cannot find anything that works.
I thought to use something similar to this:

```
SELECT index, element FROM table, CAST(message AS SUPER) AS element AT index;
```

But it doesn't take into account the length and I don't like casting a varchar variable into a super.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why would you like to do this? A single text field can hold up to 1GB of data. Or do you have more content? If so, that would fit into a large object: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens no, the size is fine. I need this for visualization and unfortunately I cannot manage this in the visualization tool.

Comment: Can’t you split the data when selecting it from the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to accomplish this:

```
  select m.*, gs.posn, substring(m.message, gs.posn, 15) as split_message 
    from messages m
         cross join lateral generate_series(1, length(message), 15) gs(posn);
```

Splitting on spaces after the length is a little trickier.  We would have to split the `message` into words and then figure out how to break them into groups and then reaggregate.

I could not figure out how to split on spaces without recursion.  I hope you don't mind that it treats all whitespace as word boundaries:

```
with recursive by_words as (
  select m.*, s.n, s.word, length(s.word) as word_len,
         max(s.n) over (partition by m.id) as num_words
    from messages m
         cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(m.message, '\s+') 
           with ordinality as s(word, n)
), rejoin as (
  select id, n, array[word] as words, word_len as cum_word_len, 
         word_len >= 15 as keep 
    from by_words
   where n = 1
  union all
  select p.id, c.n, 
         case 
           when p.cum_word_len >= 15 then array[c.word]
           else p.words||c.word
         end as words, 
         case 
           when p.cum_word_len >= 15 then c.word_len
           else p.cum_word_len + c.word_len + 1
         end as cum_word_len,
         (p.cum_word_len + c.word_len + 1 >= 15)
           or (c.n = c.num_words) as keep
    from rejoin p
         join by_words c on (c.id, c.n) = (p.id, p.n + 1)
)
select id, 
       row_number() over (partition by id
                              order by n) as segnum,
       array_to_string(words, ' ') as split_message
  from rejoin 
 where keep
 order by 1, 2
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3f6deba14fa1744c2e2850dcfdca93af)*

Edit to add:

Can you please tell me whether the below works in Redshift?

```
with gs as (
  select generate_series as posn
    from generate_series(1, 150000, 15)
)
select *, substring(m.message, gs.posn, 15) as split_message
  from messages m
       join gs 
         on gs.posn <= greatest(1, length(m.message))
 order by m.id, gs.posn
;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I accepted your solution because I saw it's correct (and also well explained, so thanks a lot) but unfortunately I'm using Redshift and generate_series is very limited - I always forget there are some Postgres function that are not well supported in Redshift -. Do you know an easy way to substitute generate_series with something else? I tried using row_number() and then multiplied the result by 15 but I have error in the substring()

Comment: @solopiu Thank you for accepting.  Sorry this does not solve your problem.  I think the problem might be with the lateral join.  Can you please see whether the new query I just added to my answer works for you in Redshift?

Comment: It does not work, I have this error `ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`. I searched for that and basically it's because generate_series runs on leader node while the rest of the queries on the compute nodes. (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326426/amazon-redshift-error-error-0a000-specified-types-or-functions-one-per-info).
But I solved the problem! I'll create a new answer for the code if someone need that, thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mike Organek 's answer and his help I found a solution that works with Redshift too.

Problem in Mike's answer for Redshift is related to `generate_series` that is not well supported in Redshift, so here's a workaround.

```
with row as (
select t.*, row_number() over () as x
from table t -- big enough table
limit 100
),
result as
(
select (x-1)*15+1 as posn from row --change 15 to a number to split the long text with
)
select * into gs
from result
```

And then Mike's answer:

```
select *, substring(m.feedback from gs.posn for 15) as split_message
  from messages m
       join gs 
         on gs.posn <= greatest(1, length(m.message))
 order by m.id, gs.posn
```