# SPLIT_PART function fails when querying result from pg_get_cols()

Tags: string, split, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to extract column name `studyid`,`domain`,`usubjid` from data below, by running this query:

```html
select split_part(pg_get_cols,',',3)
from (
select pg_get_cols('dmhair')
  )
```

The data which i'm trying to split looks like this:

```
(matillion_demo,dmhair,studyid,"character varying(255)",1)
(matillion_demo,dmhair,domain,"character varying(255)",2)
(matillion_demo,dmhair,usubjid,"character varying(255)",3)
```

But when i run it i get error:

> SQL Error [500310] [42883]: Amazon Invalid operation:
> function split_part(record, "unknown", integer) does not exist;

Comment: If you are trying to collect/ parse metadata from Redshift you'll likely run into error 0A000 as well. The workaround for that is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326426/amazon-redshift-error-error-0a000-specified-types-or-functions-one-per-info/73950487#73950487